# Improve parsing '*arg' values

Tags: ruby, parsing

I would like to know if there is a better way (that is, less coding) to have the same `output` as the following code:

```
# arg = :a, :b, :c

output = args.to_a.flatten.compact.map(&:to_sym)
# => [:a, :b, :c]
```

I use the above code to parse arguments passed by a method in this way

```
`method_name(:a, :b, :c)`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any need for `to_a`, `flatten` or `compact`.

You can just do `.map(&:to_sym)` if you want to convert strings to symbols. If you're only accepting symbols, just `args` contains what you want.

```
def method_name(*args)
   p args.map(&:to_sym)
end

method_name(:a, "b", :c)
```

Output

```
[:a, :b, :c]
```